# How many non-isomorphic subpaces does $\mathbb{R}^4$ have?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Considering the vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$, I was thinking of the following basis:

- $\emptyset$, the zero point $(0,0,0,0)$.
- $\{(1,0,0,0)\}$, $\{(0,1,0,0)\}$, $\{(0,0,1,0)\}$ and $\{(0,0,0,1)\}$. These are 4 subspaces of dimension 1 each, but am I correct in assuming they are all isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and thus I should only count 1?
- $\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0)\}$, and other combinations of two orthonormal basis which I am assuming are isomorphic.
- $\{1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)\}$ and other combinations of three orthonormal basis.
- $\{1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$ which is $\mathbb{R}^4$.

So by this logic there are 5 non-isomorphic subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Is this correct?

Comment: $\{(1,0,0,0)\}$ is not a subspace; it doesn't satisfy any of the axioms. Also $\emptyset \neq \{(0,0,0,0)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The point, here, is that two real vector spaces with finite dimension are isomorphic if their dimension is the same. So you can have subspaces with dimension: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Note however that in every intermediate dimension there are infinitely many subspaces of that dimension. For example to have a subspace of dimension $1$ you can take the space generated by any non-zero vector and they are different if you take vectors which are not one the multiple of the other.

Comment: Thanks. So in general for $\mathbb{R}^n$, would it be correct to say there are $n+1$ non-isomorphic subspaces?

Comment: yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

What you’re calling subspaces are in fact only **bases** for subspaces of $\Bbb R^4$. There are many subspaces besides the these. For example, $\{\langle x,2x,3x,4x\rangle:x\in\Bbb R\}$ is a one-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ different from all of the subspaces that you’ve listed.

The crucial point is that for any $n\in\Bbb N$, every $n$-dimensional vector space over the field $\Bbb R$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. In particular, every subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$ for some $n$. What are the candidates for $n$? Clearly $n\le 4$, so $n$ must be $0,1,2,3$, or $4$. You’ve displayed bases for subspaces of each of these dimensions, so you’ve established that $\Bbb R^4$ has at least $5$ pairwise non-isomorphic subspaces, and the dimension argument given above shows that there can be no more than that. Thus, your answer of $5$ is correct, though your argument is insufficient to show that.